# keep receiving negative numbers in total

Tags: visual-c++

For this project, you will create a program that asks the user to enter a positive integer value less than 20.

If the user enters a number greater than 20, the user should get an error.

If the user enters a number equal to or less than 20, display the double of each value beginning with 1 up to the selected number (multiply each number by 2), then provide the total of all doubles.

For example, if the user entered the number 5, the following should display:

Double up 1 = 2

Double up 2 = 4

Double up 3 = 6

Double up 4 = 8

Double up 5 = 10

Total = 30

Minimum Requirements:

Create a class that has 3 public functions.
A mutator function should take the number from the user and store it in a private variable.
Another function should perform the calculations, display the double up results and store the total in a private variable. This function must use a loop.
An accessor function should display the total.
Create a main function that creates an object of your class and calls each of the functions of the class.

```css
#include <iostream>
#include "Helloworld.h"

int main()
{
 
 Double DF;
  DF.getnumber();
  DF.cal();
  DF. getTotal();
  
  system("pause");
}
```

```html
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>


class Double 
{
  public: 
   void getnumber();
   void Double::cal();
   void getTotal();
 private:
 int int1;
   int counter;
 int total;
 
};
void Double::getnumber()
{
 std::cout << "Enter a positive  integer value that is less than 20. ";
 std::cin  >> int1;
while(int1 > 20)
{
 std::cout << "Error, Please enter a valid positive integer value less than 20: ";
 std::cin >> int1;
     }
}

void Double::cal()
{
 for ( int counter=1; counter<= int1; counter++)
 {
   std::cout <<"Double up = " << counter *2 <<std::endl;
  
}
           }


void Double::getTotal() 
{
   total = counter;
   
 std::cout << " The total amount for the double up " << int1 << " is " << total<<std::endl;
 
}
```

Comment: `Double::counter` is never assigned a value. It contains random garbage. Taking a step back, it's unclear how you expect your program to produce a sum of anything, when it never ever uses `+` addition operator.

Comment: Can I do your homework for you? I can, but I won't.

Comment: I was asking for an example. I didn't ask you to do my homework for me, HOMIE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate sum of these double numbers use Mathematical formula `(n*(n+1))`
The variable **counter** you are using in `getTotal()` is never initialize as variable **counter** in function `cal()` is local variable to same function only.

As variable `counter` is not initialized its given garbage value.

```
void Double::getTotal() 
{
   total = (int1*(int1+1));  // use this formula to get total

    std::cout << " The total amount for the double up " << int1 << " is " << total<<std::endl;

}
```

suppose `int1 = 5` then

```
Total = (int1 * (int1 + 1));
Total = (5 * (5 + 1))
Total = (5 * 6);
Total = 30;
```